# Python 2.7 tkinter listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to delete item from a listbox by its name? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
for name in re.findall('name\=\\"(.*?)\\\"', msg, re.DOTALL):
    listBox.delete(0, name)
```

but error occurred:

```
TclError: bad listbox index "something3647": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number
```

Names are random. It looks like I can insert something by its name but not delete it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't delete by name. You can't really insert it "by name" either. Both insertion and deletion requires an index. However, it's only a couple lines of code to search the listbox for the item by name, and then delete the item that you found.